# Determine location gps and wifi

Tags: android, location

I want to show a dialog while the location of the device is determined. I also want to use both the wifi and gps provider. When the location changes, the latitude and longitude values should be updated. I looked for an example but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Take a look on this example:


[How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android/12963889#12963889

Comment: Check out some [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html). Then Toast `onLocationChanged()` or something

Comment: read this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: you can not use both GPS & WiFi at same time.

Comment: apparently you don't know about this site: developer.android.com is all in there.